# Convert Json string to IFormFile in .NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to convert a JSON string into a FormFile (using .net core 6).

Options I tried:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content)));

var formFile = new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, memoryStream.Length, "test", "test.json")
{
   ContentType = "application/json",
   Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
};
```

// OR

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content)));
    
var formFile = new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, memoryStream.Length, "test", "test.json");
```

In both solutions I got a `NullReferenceException`, saying that `ContentDisposition` and `ContentType` cannot be null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> In both solutions I got a NullReferenceException, saying that
> ContentDisposition and ContentType cannot be null.

First of all if your navigate to [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-7.0) Interface you would seen [ContentDisposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.contentdisposition?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iformfile-contentdisposition) and [ContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.contenttype?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iformfile-contenttype) property. While sending request make sure you have value there. If you send any file it should contain its ContentDisposition details like name, request type and so on as you can see below:

[image]

**Note:**

Make sure, you are getting value for ContentDisposition and ContentType on your request. If you don't have those value it would ended up with the exception you are getting now. Thus, please check your request and content details.

**Json To IFromFile Conversion:**

I have tested to send a file and extracted the reqeust as json file and finally save it into a directory int following way.

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/JsonToIFrom")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> JsonToIFrom([FromForm] APIRequestModel content)
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content)));

            var formFile = new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, memoryStream.Length, "test", "test.json");
            var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "WriteIFromJson/", formFile.FileName);


            using (FileStream streamFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(streamFile);
                streamFile.Close();
            }
            return Ok(content);
        }
```

Request Model:

```cs
public class APIRequestModel
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public IFormFile MyByteData { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]